# How can I get the Return value of onBeforeUnload

Tags: javascript

I want to do a certain action based on, what the user clicks due to onbeforeunload event. For ex, if the user clicks on "stay on current page" then do some action, else do something else.

I am not getting anyway to fetch the return value of onbeforeunload and do some action based on that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, unfortunately.  Well, not directly.  `onbeforeunload` asks the browser to open a dialog, and it doesn't tell you the outcome.

One thing you can do is have a global variable set to `false`, and when `onbeforeunload` is triggered, set it to `true`.  Then you can have a `setInterval` checking that variable, and when it's true, assume they clicked 'stay'.

There is also `onunload` which you can use when the user does leave the page, so you can run some JavaScript when they leave, but you cannot redirect them or prevent them from leaving.

I made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QxrkD/1/

Watch the console when you click on either 'leave' or 'stay' after clicking on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

1. After the user does not click "stay on current page," they will navigate away from your page, which means that you're not really going to be able to run any more JavaScript.
2. Callback return values are (generally) only consumed by the higher-level code which invokes the callback for you. The whole *point* of a callback is that it is executed at some (generally unknown and usually [relatively] unimportant) point in the future. So, *you* (generally) can't rely on returning anything from a callback, since you don't know when it will be executed.  So — you (generally) need to think about solving the problem differently.